# Return a dataframe of averages from a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, mean

I have a list of 22 dataframes each is 49 columns and 497 rows.

I need to produce an average/mean dataframe from these 22.

Already tried these, myfiles2 is the list of dataframes

```r
    ans1 = aaply(laply(myfiles2, as.matrix), c(2, 3), mean)

    ans2 <- do.call("mean", myfiles2)

    ans3 <- lapply(myfiles2, function (x) lapply(x, mean, na.rm=TRUE))

    ans4 <- Reduce("+", myfiles2)/length(myflies2)

    ans5 <- lapply(myfiles2, mean)
```

The list of dataframes was created using

```r
    myfiles2 = lapply(filesToProcess, read.csv, skip=2, colClasses=colClasses)
```

Taking the first value in each dataframe manually and calculating the mean with mean() works.

Trying to use mean or calculating it as shown above across the list of dataframes gives an incorrect result.

The result I'm looking for is a `[49X497]` dataframe with each location containing the mean calculated from the same location in the 22 dataframes.

All values are 10 significant figures with 4 decimal places.

Comment: Do you need an elementwise mean. What is the issue with `ans4`?  You haven't provided a reproducible example.  `myfiles2 <- list(mtcars, mtcars); Reduce(`+`, myfiles2)/length(myfiles2)` works for me.  However, if there are NA elements, this wouldn't work

Comment: ans4 just does not produce the correct result. I'm not sure why either it seemed the simplest to me. The result from the use of mean() is 485223.06686364 calculating it across the dataframes the result is 485222.219. all are numeric with no NAs

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, i showed a reproducible example and it iss giving the correct output.  If you don't provide a small reprodducible example and keep saying that it is not giving correct result, it is difficult for others to help you

Comment: What about binding all your dataframe in a general one, making sure you have a extra variable to differenciate them. You can simply use `group_by` and `summarise` from the dplyr package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the hint from @tom above the final solution arrived at was to change the list of data frames to a single data frame with all data and use the tidyverse to process it.

There were a few little tidy ups needed.

1. An errant character column from the origin of the data
2. A column with data in both upper and lower case
3. Avoiding the character columns in the mean calculation
4. Then putting the character columns and the mean data frame back together to get it back in the correct order.

So...

Change the format to a single data frame and fix the non-numeric column

```
myfiles3 <- myfiles2 %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  transform(EdgeStepL2 = as.numeric(EdgeStepL2))
```

ensure the section names are in uppercase to be consistent

```
myfiles3$Section <- str_to_upper(myfiles3$Section)
```

calculate the mean of each cell grouped by common values.

```
myfiles4 <- myfiles3 %>% group_by(Section,Chainage) %>%
  summarise_at(vars("East":"Surf.Det"),funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))

myfiles5 <- data.frame(myfiles2[[1]][1:2])

myfiles6 <- left_join(myfiles5, myfiles4)
```

This is not the simple solution I had hoped for but for the next person to try this.

Look for the NA's (everywhere in the data).

Make sure that all the columns you are running the mean (or other function) on are those you can calculate with.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `simplify2array()` in base R.

#### Example

```
list1
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    9    8    3
# [2,]    5    2    6   11
# [3,]   12    4   10    7
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    4   12    3    6
# [2,]    9    2    1    7
# [3,]    5    8   10   11
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    5    8    1   12
# [2,]    4    3    7    6
# [3,]    2   10   11    9

t(apply(simplify2array(list1), 1:2, mean))
#          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
# [1,] 3.333333 6.000000  6.333333
# [2,] 9.666667 2.333333  7.333333
# [3,] 4.000000 4.666667 10.333333
# [4,] 7.000000 8.000000  9.000000
```

#### Data

```
set.seed(42)
list1 <- replicate(3, matrix(sample(1:12), 3, 4), simplify=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `abind` package to create a 3D array from your list of data.frames;

```r
library(abind)
myfiles2 <- abind(myfiles2, along = 3)
```

or in Base R:

```r
myfiles2 <- simplify2array(myfiles2)
```

Then, use `apply()` to take the mean for each cell across all 22 data.frames:

```r
apply(myfiles2, 1:2, mean)
```